# Как в WooCommerce добавить в фильтр наличия товара опцию "Под заказ"?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

У меня используется тема WoodMart в ней есть стандартный stock filter, но у меня есть товары которые на заказ, как добавить эту опцию в фильтр?